# Huge Increase in VMDK size when cloning

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I have an Ubuntu VMDK which I created using VMware Fusion and it sits at around ~2GB. When I clone the VMDK over to an ESXi 6.0 server and run the `vmkfstools -i` command to copy the VMDK, it produces a new VMDK with 68GB in size... It works fine, but the huge increase in size really makes me wonder why? It cloned with the `-d thin` flag so I thought it would be much smaller.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that your vm doesnt have it's ram reserved for it. i had this problem with vm that has 500gb RAM and no reservation so in normal times it had a swap file of 500gb and in the time of vmotion it doubled it and expload the shared datastore.. is your ram size is 68GB?
check [this](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.resmgmt.doc%2FGUID-AC40823A-695B-438A-A8F2-4B7C51A0D014.html) post to see if it make things clearer you can check for vmware swap files in google too